# Can't show One Choice Items in AlertDialog android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I try to create `AlertDialog` with `radiobuttons`, but they don't show.
I want, that user choose sort-case (like on time, or on name).
This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Select sorting type:")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(m_aNames,1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                            switch (selectedPosition) {
                                case 0:
                                    Log.d("lMA", "Sort By Time");
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    Log.d("lMA", "Sort By Name");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            }  );
            builder.show();
```

Comment: What is the problem???

Comment: where is your radio button in this code

Comment: setSingleChoiceItems - must create a radiobutton. I fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setMessage` use `setTitle`. you can not have message and radio buttons together.